# Casting text type column to json type in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, casting

I have column typed text in my database which has json queries in it. I want to cast type of the column to json in postgresql how can I do that?

```
UPDATE category_query_copy
set json_queries = query_json
```

my query is like this and the error message:

[Err] ERROR:  column "json_queries" is of type json but expression is of type text

LINE 2: set json_queries = query_json
                   ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: The chapter "Type Casts" in manual will tell you: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: I tried it already doesn't work

Comment: Well, you have no cast in your SQL. The chapter "*Type Casts*" in the manual will tell you how to properly cast one type to another: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PostgreSQL is fussy about data types, and won't *implicitly* convert from `text` to `json` even though they seem like they're both textual types.

You must use an explicit cast, e.g.

```
UPDATE category_query_copy
set json_queries = CAST(query_json AS json)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but for some reasons, using cast function does not work on my side. This is what has worked

```
UPDATE category_query_copy
set json_queries = to_json(query_json)
```